# how to hide locked tickets in overview?

Tags: otrs

I recently upgraded from OTRS 2.2 to OTRS 3.1. The new user interface is awesome, but on the overview page both panels "open tickets" and "new tickets" also show tickets already locked by other users (ie. those that are already being handled by other agents).

Is there a way to *only show unlocked new tickets* and those *locked by me*?

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer: I know how to make the "open ticket" and "new ticket" widgets on the dashboard to display unlocked tickets. To get the ones locked by you i am not sure.

1. login as admin and go to admin tab
2. Click on sysconfig and do a search for "dashoboard"
3. Choose the "Frontend:Agent:Dahsboard" belonging to group "Ticket"
4. Scroll down to DashboardBackend###0120-TicketNew (this is the new ticket widget)
5. Under Attributes add more attributes to meet your needs. For showing only unlocked tickets add "StateType=new;LockIDs=1;" so now you will have all new tickets that are unlocked. use LockIDs=2 for locked ones.

To view other attributes go to [API](http://dev.otrs.org/)  -> OTRS cvs -> Kernel::System::TicketSearch

I do not know how to get unlocked ones && locked by me.
Maybe you can add code to view the owner or locked unlocked status of the ticket in the widget to meet your requirements? If so see [here](http://wiki.otterhub.org/index.php?title=Show_Customer_Data_in_Dashboard) and [here](http://forums.otterhub.org/viewtopic.php?f=60&t=5156)